# Automating Portlet Deployment to WebSphere Portal Server 6.1

Tags: java, ant, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

I've recently started on a project to develop some portlets which will run on IBM WebSphere Portal Server 6.1.

Does anyone know of any scripts, Ant tasks, Maven plugins, etc. for publishing a portlet to Portal Server? In the WebSphere Portlet Factory plugin for eclipse it is possible to "publish" a portlet project to Portal Server instance, however I'd like to know what's going on underneath the hood here (or at least how to replicate the behaviour) so that I can do it in other places (i.e. from continuous integration server).

UPDATE: From what I've read it sounds like the Portlet Factory publishes using a WebSphere JMX client. Does anyone know where I can find more details on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some documentation on the WebSphere Portal site entitled "[Portal administration tools](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/admin/admtools.html)" which lists a few options:

- The portal administration portlets.
- The portal XML configuration interface.
- The Portal Scripting Interface.
- The portal ReleaseBuilder.

The XML configuration interface and the scripting interface sound like they might be what I'm looking for, as these could easily be called from an automated process.

I also found an example of [a Java program which uses the WebSphere JMX interface](http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/15/automating-websphere-using-jmx/), however I don't know if this would also work for WebSphere Portal...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tooling for automated deployment.

Take a look at Deployit from Xebialabs. On http://www.xebialabs.com you can download a free version for WAS and they also have a plug-in for Portal.